# Issue with NVDA in a table

Tags: keyboard, screen, accessibility, nvda

I have a table and in a cell I have a word and an icon. Having first the word and after that the icon the NVDA reader can't read it (I use the Tab button to move from the one cell to another).

If I use the vice versa combination, icon first - word after, it can read all of them.

What could I do to read the word first and the icon second?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you link an example? Perhaps a fiddle or a codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround could be to have the word after that the icon and after that a character and the reader can read everything.